# Greenify blocked

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, optimization, greenify

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S4 rooted device.
I have greenify installed on it but I receive an orange error box on the bottom of the page saying this "auto hibernation service is being blocked by 3rd party tool or system settings (e.g.stamina mode in sony devi es. autostart manager in MIUI) Please whitelist greenify for automatic hibernation to work."

in setting I made greenify a device administrator but it didn't solve the issue.

any idea how to fix this?

for security software I have 360 security and it doesn't have any setting about white list (I don't think the problem is from 360)

Comment: Do you have the S4's "Power saving" mode turned on? You can find it in the quick settings in the notification tray, as well as the main settings app.

Comment: Does Power saver block greenify?

Comment: That's what the error message says.

Comment: Power saveing mode was off.

Comment: Are you running a third party ROM or the stock Samsung firmware? I've a rooted S4 here with Greenify and I've never seen that before.

Comment: I m rooted. Have cwm custom recovery . Never unlocked bootloader .

Comment: @RossC  do you know how to unlock bootloader for s4?  I have SGH - I337M   samsung firmware

Comment: I don't think there is an unlock for it, or at least I'm not aware of one. You shouldn't need to. Are you on the Stock ROM or did you flash a custom one?

Comment: @RossC No I didn't install any custom rom

Answer (score 2):

Problem  solved. 360 security was crashing with greenify.if you open the main page of 360 security then memory booster on top right hand side there is a ignore list. Add greenify to ignore list and you will be ok. It seems greenify and 360 security do the same function and when you run both at same time 360 tries to hibernate greenify which causes this problem.